# Symfony 3 create Atribute of a manyToMany relation in a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, manytomanyfield

I try to create a form that allows me to create a new profile and to answer some questions during the creation.
My questions are already in the database.
My 3 entities are `subject`- `question` - `answer`.

Subject :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="Subject", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $Answers;
```

Answer:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject",inversedBy="Answer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subject_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Subject;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question",inversedBy="Answer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Question;
```

Question

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $text;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="Question")
 */
private $Answer;
```

---

I tried many solutions but I dont know how to deal with the form creation and controller data reception. Any help for find the right method to use will be apreciated.

Comment: a new profile... a user profile? so you should have a User entity too?

Comment: You should really stick to symfony coding standards (http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html), in this case using camelCase for variable names.